# What is the default behavior for a single credential group with multiple authentication mechanisms?

Tags: security, authentication, cookies, google-search-appliance

I'm trying to get a better understanding of how the GSA authenticates users.

We have a GSA search configured with multiple cookie authn mechs under the same credential group. From the logs, it looks like users must pass authentication with all of those mechanisms -- not just one. Is this the intended behavior?

I would expect users to only need one mechanism to validate their authentication before the GSA performs the search.

In the failure log, the GSA goes through all four mechanisms and only one verifies the user. No results are returned and there is no "Authentication successful!" line.
In the success log, the three mechanisms that were refuting the user have been removed. Results are returned.

This seems strange to me. I'm still looking but I haven't found any documentation about this yet. Has anyone else run into this?

Failure log:

```
150249 16:24:19.593 [Authentication] New session for this request: 744e33ce2597dc4391a173c3d99cd6d8
150249 16:24:19.600 [Authentication] running AuthN mechanism SAML
150249 16:24:19.602 [Authentication] Redirecting user to be authenticated by the Security Manager: <filtered>
150249 16:24:19.746 [Security Manager] Incoming cookies from user agent: <filtered>
150249 16:24:19.909 [Security Manager] Attempting to authenticate using pre-existing credentials.
150249 16:24:20.076 [Security Manager] The credentials were refuted by cred_mech1
150249 16:24:20.170 [Security Manager] The credentials were refuted by cred_mech2
150249 16:24:20.180 [Security Manager] The credentials were refuted by cred_mech3
150249 16:24:20.207 [Security Manager] The credentials were verified by cred_mech4
150249 16:24:20.213 [Security Manager] GroupsUpdateModule Auth: Looking up groups for user: <filtered>
150249 16:24:20.226 [Security Manager] GroupsUpdateModule did not find groups for: scope: 1
name: "<filtered>"
name_space: "Default"
case_sensitive: 0

150249 16:24:20.229 [Security Manager] The credentials were verified by Default_groups_1a852798543f79b0afe8af1789f9bb0c
150249 16:24:20.234 [Security Manager] Unable to authenticate with pre-existing credentials. Starting credentials gathering.
150249 16:24:20.237 [Security Manager] Not trying Universal Login Form because no remaining credential group can use it.
150249 16:24:20.244 [Security Manager] Not trying Universal Login Form because no remaining credential group can use it.
150249 16:24:20.251 [Security Manager] Not trying Universal Login Form because no remaining credential group can use it.
150249 16:24:20.259 [Security Manager] Outgoing cookies to user agent: (none)
```

Success log:

```
150249 15:42:29.269 [Authentication] New session for this request: 75fa3613c48c3b505aa8cc681cd142aa
150249 15:42:29.277 [Authentication] running AuthN mechanism SAML
150249 15:42:29.280 [Authentication] Redirecting user to be authenticated by the Security Manager: <filtered>
150249 15:42:29.496 [Security Manager] Incoming cookies from user agent: <filtered>
150249 15:42:29.669 [Security Manager] Attempting to authenticate using pre-existing credentials.
150249 15:42:29.917 [Security Manager] The credentials were verified by cred_mech4
150249 15:42:29.925 [Security Manager] GroupsUpdateModule Auth: Looking up groups for user: <filtered>
150249 15:42:29.940 [Security Manager] GroupsUpdateModule did not find groups for: scope: 1
name: "<filtered>"
name_space: "Default"
case_sensitive: 0

150249 15:42:29.943 [Security Manager] The credentials were verified by Default_groups_1a852798543f79b0afe8af1789f9bb0c
150249 15:42:29.948 [Security Manager] Outgoing cookies to user agent: (none)
150249 15:42:30.229 [Authentication] Authentication successful!  Search user identity is: <filtered> ; session: 75fa3613c48c3b505aa8cc681cd142aa
150249 15:42:30.236 [Authentication] Verified credential: <filtered>, namespace: Default
150249 15:42:30.238 [Authentication] Authentication expiration time is: 20150218T154729.673-0600
150249 15:42:30.270 [Authentication] Redirecting user to relayState value: <fitlered>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that the GSA isn't really intended to use one
credential group with multiple authentication mechanisms, unless one
of those "authentication" mechanisms is really only being used for
group lookups. That's the point of having multiple credential groups.
How would late-binding authorization work if you could have multiple
authentication mechanisms within a single credential group, for
example? Would it only use the authentication mechanism that succeeded
for authorization checks?

If you want to provide multiple authorization paths, even if the
corresponding authentication mechanisms all point to the same user
repository under the covers, you're going to need to provide multiple
credential groups. And if you want to have multiple authentication
mechanisms that point to different user repositories, you definitely
want to use multiple credential groups.

Comment: Dave is right, a credential group is meant for mechanisms that share a common user identity. 
From the doco: A credential group is an administrator-defined set of domains that share a user directory or use duplicated user directories. You might think of a credential group as all the login services that use the same username and password.

Comment: Thanks -- we were running into an issue with a connector not correctly assigning a global namespace to indexed items, so we were stuck with all items in the "Default" namespace and were wondering if there was a way to make that work. This clears that up, though.

Comment: Sorry for the double-comment -- meant to put this in one.

Anyway, we also noticed during some more testing that the GSA will accept authentication for a user even when it cannot receive verification from all auth mechs in the credential group as long as all _reachable_ auth mechs verify the user. E.g., if some auth mech servers are down then the remaining can still verify. Regardless, sounds like we should still use separate credential groups anyway.

Answer (score 1):

One credential group means one identity. If you have multiple cookie based auth mechanism, they need to go to separate credential groups.